# How to extract only the numerical values from a column (varchar) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, linux

sorry if  it was asked before , but I couldn't find anything helpful. Using MySQL 5.7 , I've got  the column "Statistics" which has the following format {"Births:" 21678 }. How can I select only the numeric value ?

For example :

```
Name              Statistics 

Amsterdam         {"Births:" 23456}

Chicago           {"Births:" 67890}
```

And I would want the output to be :

```
Name         Births 

Amsterdam    23456

Chicago      67890
```

I suppose I should use REGEXP ,but nothing seems to work in my case .

Name and Births are both columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use also string function

```
select 
   name
 , SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Statistics , 1, CHAR_LENGTH(Statistics ) -1), 
   POSITION(' ' IN  SUBSTRING(Statistics , 1, CHAR_LENGTH(Statistics) - 1)), 100) AS Births
from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, because REGEXP will only work in a WHERE clause but not in the select. If your *Statistics-column* only and always contains the *Births*, you can do something like

```
SELECT select MID(Statistics, 11, LENGTH(Statistics)-11) FROM table
```

But this will only work with the given example above. If statistics differ, this approach will not work.

If you have a mysql-server version 5.7.8 or greater, you can use JSON functions. Should be

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(Statistics, 'Births') from table
```